# Coverage measurment action in gyp

Tags: gcov, gyp

I decided to use [gyp](http://code.google.com/p/gyp) as a build system for my project on linux. I am happy with basic functionality (target declarations, dependencies, hierarchies etc.) but I have some problems with customization.

I have a Core project which is built as a library and bunch of unit tests for the library which compiles into separate executable and has core project as a dependency. Now I want to measure test coverage with `gcov` and it means that the library itself should be built with different compilation options, and these options should be used only for test build.

I just can't realize how to achieve this with gyp. Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution and decided to share it. What I actually needed is just to add another [configuration](http://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/GypLanguageSpecification#configurations):

```
'configurations': {
  # Or just let Debug configuration turn on coverage
  'Coverage': {
    'conditions': [
      ['OS=="linux"', {
          'cflags': ['--coverage'],
          'ldflags': ['-fprofile-arcs']
        }],
    ]
  },
  # More configurations
}
```

UPD: Looks like there is another way to do it - specify additional coverage flags inside `direct_dependent_settings` dictionary of the `test` target.